# DynamoDB: Batch update without aborting transaction if one or more update fails

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to perform a DynamoDB batch update where I want to update multiple items in a batch (or transaction).

I've tried using a `TransactWrite` query, which does work with batching the updates, however if one of the updates fails the entire transaction fails which I do not want.

I would ideally want similar functionality to `BatchWrite`, but at the time of writing that does not support updates.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html) [`BatchExecuteStatement`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.multiplestatements.batching.html) to achieve your use-case.

- The entire batch must consist of either read statements or write statements; you cannot mix both in one batch.
- BatchExecuteStatement just like BatchWriteItem can perform no more than 25 statements per batch.